# How to change the background-color of a Bootstrap card-header?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the `background-color` of a bootstrap `card-header`, but when I add `background-color: #00AA9E` it seems to somehow destroy the look of the header..? Has anyone ever seen this before? Does it have something to do with the fact that the card is nested? Is it a bug in bootstrap?

[Before  `background-color: #00AA9E`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29I27.png)

[After  `background-color: #00AA9E`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTNIE.png)

Comment: please show us code in codepen or jsfiddle.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found a fix, I set the card's (not card-header) `background-color` to `#00AA9E`, and then set the card body to white. Probably not the right way to do it but it did the job for me. :)

Comment: If you have to put 'Probably not the right way to do it but...' into your answer, you probably shouldn't mark it as the answer as that may discourage someone who knows how to do it correctly from answering and providing the right way to do it.

Answer (score 14):

First off, since you're setting the font-color to white, just use the `text-white` class.

However, I do not have the same issue whenever I use this code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header text-white" style="background-color: #00AA9E;">
      Featured
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there something else that could be affecting the style that you aren't showing us?

Comment: No, the div looks like: ` <div class="card-header task-header text-center text-white" >` where task-header only sets the background-color

Comment: Works fine, ty.

Comment: David, you used an inline style tag which is overriding the background color set by the card-header class.  If I may assume, I think OP wants to know how to make the background color setting in their class 'task-header' override the background color of the card-header class.

Comment: You realize that this question is over two and a half years old right?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's years later, but I figured I'd add my answer since the accepted answer is a roundabout way of doing this and there is a more straightforward way to do it.  Applying `!important` to the setting(s) in your css class will cause them to override all settings set in another css class on the same element.  Hope this helps someone.

```css
.ph-card-header {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: navy !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Bootstrap 5 you can add a couple of additional classes: bg-dark & text-white.